# Update multiple values of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given an object

```
var myObject = {
    label: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    id: 12
},
```

If I wanted to change multiple values, I would do the following:

```
myObject.label = "bar";
myObject.name = "foo";
```

When updating large sets of data, it makes the code quite blocky. Is there a way to do this in a more concise manner?

Like:

```
myObject.({label: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'});
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is nice for this:

```js
var myObject = {
    label: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    id: 12
}
Object.assign(myObject, {label: 'Test', name: 'Barbar'})
console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: Using Vuex objects in the states this is the recommended way if you want to keep the Vue.js reactivity.

Answer (score 17):

In addition to `Object.assign`, you can also use the object spread operator:

```js
var myObject = {
    label: 'foo',
    name: 'bar',
    id: 12
};

myObject = {...myObject, label: 'baz', name: 'qux'};
console.log(myObject);

// Or, if your update is contained in its own object:

var myUpdate = {
    label: 'something',
    name: 'else'
}

myObject = {...myObject, ...myUpdate}
console.log(myObject)
```

Comment: Unlike `Object.assign`, this doesn’t actually “update” the object, it makes a whole new one, so if `myObject` is aliased the original version will remain visible there unchanged. That may or may not be ok.